# include searched regex text also in output

Tags: regex, python-re, findall, textmatching

I'm using regex `re.findall(r"[0-9]+(.*?)\.\s(.*?)[0-9]+", text)` to get below text

```
8    EXT./INT. MONORAIL - MORNING 8
9    EXT. CITY SCAPE/MONORAIL - CONTINUOUS 9
```

But my current output doesn't have the prefix and suffix numbers. I'm trying to have the prefix digits also in the output as follows.

```
9    EXT. CITY SCAPE/MONORAIL - CONTINUOUS
```

Any help greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

(The current output is given below)

[image: current output]

Comment: Include the numbers in the capturing groups? Put them in their own groups? It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Marked as answer and upvoted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use

```js
(?m)^([0-9]+)\s*(.*?)\.\s(.*?)(?:\s*([0-9]+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l1WFbb/3). **Details*:

- `(?m)` - a multiline modifier
- `^` - start of string
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\.\s` - a dot and a whitespace
- `(.*?)` - Group 3: zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s*([0-9]+))?` - an optional occurrence of zero or more whitespaces and then Group 4 capturing one or more digits
- `$` - end of line.